No Fallout Orbital WMDs
I’ve asked a lot of people I know this, and no one has a good answer.
In my world, a UN type organization has united numerous multi-solar system nations against an aggressive, racist confederation of systems. Their goal is much like the Allies’ in WWII, to pacify the confederation and return invaded planets to the invaded. As such, weapons with any lasting fallout are forbidden.
Also unfortunately, underground bases have been created in secret locations on all the invaded planets, so ground forces have to be sent down to locate these bunkers for Rods From God strikes. These forward bases will come under attack by the millions of hostile, so I need a WMD with a set radius to protect them from close range. To be clear, is there an orbital weapon that could deal with large amounts of infantry relatively (within 1 mile) of friendlies?
Note: everyone has access, at least in a limited degree, to a very dense, hard alloy made from a new element. It is used as armor widely, and so blocks the use of radiation.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Also, I can not find what a "THOR strike" is. I don't put it past my google-fu to have failed me, but if it's something specific to your setting, we could use an explanation. Further framing of your answer, regarding the level of tech and the ressources available, would help (something to keep in mind for future questions).

@Nyakouai It's a short/medium range ICBM system developed by the US and adopted by Britain - way back in the late 1950s (Cold-War era). See Britannica article for details. Designed for nuclear payloads. The OP might include more details in the question.

VTC:Needs More Details. I frankly don't know what kind of answer you're looking for. You tagged the question [tag:far-future], but you're asking if there's a weapon today that can do what you want to do? What's the point? Clarke declared that a sufficiently advanced technology is indistiguishable from magic. Why aren't you trying to develop the weapon as an imaginative effort? Who cares if we can or can't do it today? Are they only using concrete in the far future? Is the bunker only a few feet underground? What research have you performed and why has it been unsuccessful?

It’s far enough into the future for large, multi-system colonialism, but because resources were focused on that for so long, tech is still futuristic but less well-developed than you’d think, so I’m trying to use real-world theories. The bunkers are very far underground, hundreds of yards, and they have to use massive tungsten rods dropped by aircraft to destroy them.

If you are already using Rods From God why can't you use the same tech to do the job you need? You don't need to penetrate deep underground, so it should be even more economical just to wrap some slag/rocks in an ablative heat shielding plastic and drop them on the enemy.

You have WMD and you are air dropping tungsten rods to destroy underground bunkers? Just dropping from in atmosphere? I'm more confused by the minute. Also, far future tag, but "tech is less well developed than you think"... That does not really help people answer your question. I think it needs more clarity and to be narrowed down.

According to recent research, Rods From God penetrate furthest at Mach 3.5, and orbit is too high for that.

You ask for something that can be deployed from space to take out a large area of attacking infantry but not harm your base. You seem to be asking for a cluster bomb.
An explosion will have a certain amount of energy that gets dispersed over a certain volume. It is hard to make a single explosion go out to a radius of a mile and them stop. It is easier, and more efficient to carpet the surface evenly with an array of small explosions. This could be launched from space, but you might have a faster response if you launched it from your base. Or you could even have a smart minefield. Or a swarm of armed drones. Anything that takes the explosion to the individual will do the job.
Having answered that, why would they attack you with ground troops? Maybe they took the planet by force of arms. But then you have come to take the planet back, presumably packing sufficient heat to neutralise the known threat. Is this a deterrent? Or do they want to have huge casualties to make you look bad?
Follow-up, prompted by replies:
This is supposed to be a benign intervention. The object is not to wipe out the incoming army, but to persuade them not to attack because you could. A kinetic strike from orbit would be unexpected and dramatic. A deployed smart minefield is almost the opposite. It is there. Don't walk into the danger zone. If you do, you get what you deserve.
A kinetic weapon launched from space requires a lot of mass and
energy. Once launched, all this mass and energy has been committed to making a big hole somewhere. It may take tens of minutes at least to arrive from orbit. It has to hit a moving target: a blitzkrieg unit on motorbikes could cover miles across difficult terrain in that time.
Minefields have a bad reputation. Retreating armies who do not care about the consequences scatter old munitions in poor condition and do not keep records. Years later these can kill and maim civilians that had no part of the original conflict. This does not have to happen if the minefield is well-managed.  The idea is not to blow people up but to deny them territory. The whole minefield or swarm should be capable of packing up and/or moving if the base is re-deployed. There should be guaranteed warnings before the danger starts.

They are attacking the ground bases on the surface in order to slow down or stop the finding of their bunkers. In this setting FTL takes months, so they could theoretically be rescued.

@Ike They are still attacking a ground base that was established by a force that knew how they conquered the planet, and how many troops that took, and are still confident enough to establish a base on the ground there. They must expect huge losses if they attack.

You could dispense with the explosives altogether. Just like project Thor you drop a ton of tungsten rods, though you'll either have a thousand smaller pieces or have it break apart close to the surface. You obviously do not need the same amount of force as project Thor to still have much destroyed in a mile radius. Thin, heavy rods striking from above can penetrate a lot. Not to mention their impact can still be enough to have debris exploding in every direction.

@Trioxidane Rods from God are wildly inaccurate.  Yes, they could probably be made target accurate within about a km, but if you are dropping 1000s of them, that just means 50% will hit that close while other may go many km off target. The odds of a couple outliers landing on friendliess goes way up with that many rods.  In contrast, a cluster bomb first slows down from orbital speed, adjusts its angle until it gets within a terminal range, and then spreads out into a controlled pattern giving a much more even distribution of separation.

@Nosajimiki with interstellar travel it seems much more likely that technology is accurate enough to work. In addition, my second option was indeed spreading closer to the ground.

*crack knuckles*
Aaaaaah, the joy of figuring out how to eradicate thy neighbours.

To be clear, is there an orbital weapon that could deal with large amounts of infantry relatively (within 1 mile) of friendlies?

Currently? I would guess missiles, technically, but it's just not very convenient, economically, to have weapons in orbit, with our current level of technology. So I am going to assume you are asking in the context of your hypothetical space-faring situation.
For space-faring civilisation, pretty much the same stuff that we have, just scaled up.

Missiles (again). Thermobaric bomb is something we currently have and that could be considered the step juuuust below a nuke in term of strength to apply to a military objective. If you research, a few have been deployed in Middle-East in the past decade if memory serves. I'm going to be overly simplistic and just liken that to a very big explosion. But if your missile is half smart, then it's quite safe for your friendlies near the point of impact - you know the yield of the payload, you just have to select the proper ammunition to use given the tactical situation.

Kinetic strike. Or, if you want to be less pompous, space artillery. Same as regular artillery, except you don't have to lob a ferrous slug over the horizon, you just aim it from so high you can see your target. Current days equivalent would be Naval gunfire support - after all, nothing is preventing you from pointing those very big guns on your ships towards a ground target. Takes a little more calculation work on the part of the artillery crew, since the ammunition is not going to correct its flight path like a missile would. But if you have computers for space-faring, it should be next to trivial. Never underestimate the impact of a very heavy object hurling toward the ground faster than terminal velocity.
If you want a more sci-fi vibe, your artillery pieces are electromagnetic - look for Gauss Gun, Coil Gun or Railgun (three distinct concepts)

Laser. Again, not too far-fetched. We have current days examples of laser weapons. Currently, those are designed to intercept projectiles, but they proved to be effective and accurate at range. To fire one from orbit that would retain enough energy is more than we can currently do, but in the future, it's plausible enough.
There has been concerns expressed over the consequences of laser weapons used to shoot orbital debris though - as it would/could warm the athmosphere on its path - when people were examining options to get rid of the leftovers that are littering our orbit.


Honestly, if you have spaceships, the concept of WMDs just became very relative. If you got the kind of energy required to move between the stars at a decent path, then you got the energy required to make a lot of people have a really bad day.
On the topic of energy expenditure, I don't know how tech works in your setting, but the operational consideration would mainly be on the actual pay-off of each type of weapon. Missiles, ammunition and fuel take cargo space and add weight that you have to get into orbit. Not all weapons are equally useful in all scenarios. If you have to bust bunkers, my money would not be on laser weapons. If you want fast deployment to target infantry, then missiles and slugs have nothing on the speed of light. Each could potentially be used for space-warfare. The fine details are too open-ended given the current amount of information. I just listed possible options that are plausible - but it's nothing new, both in fiction or, as you can see, reality.

If you can get between planets quickly, all you have to do to destroy an enemy base is send a droneship on a trajectory towards the planet and then tell it not to slow down at the end.

@controlgroup Yeah, point I was thinking about in the comment. In this case, the question asked for a controlled area blast, not to eradicate an enemy base. But to be fair, I'd give pretty much the same answer to bust bunkers. And in the end... suicide drone, missile... potato potato, the difference is the payload you put on board.

They use Alcubierre drives, in which space is warped and the ship does not change speed, so dropping stuff in a flyby doesn’t work, and building a drone with one would be both dangerous to use around friendly vessels and very expensive. The planet being intact would also be nice for resettlement.

Hafnium Bomb
While the truth behind early Hafnium Bomb experiments is contested, and experiments are hampered by current technological limitations in purifying Hafnium, it remains theoretically possible to use Hafnium to make micronuclear weapons.  A Hafnium reaction could in theory be used to make special kinds of nukes that are much smaller and cleaner than traditional Uranium or Plutonium based nukes.  The problem with current mini-nukes like the W54 is that part of their low yield is because they only react a very small fraction of their radioactive material causing a lot of fallout for the size of the blast, but similarly powerful Hafnium Bombs could achieve near total reactions due to their lower total energy density. So, if you wanted to drop something bigger than a thermobaric or cluster munitions bomb, but much less radioactive than a typical nuke, then Hafnium bombs give you a good middle ground between the two.

The fundamental problem is that the claims of induced gamma emission were not reproducible. Given the effort that went into trying, it seems clear that it doesn't work.

@JohnDallman It's also [far-future] with FTL travel. We're clearly allowing apparently-impossible tech, aren't we?

Alcubierre drives may be viable within a few decades, but Hafnium bombs might work with some handwavium

There were proposals in the fifties for a large rifle bullet with a nuclear warhead based on a Californium isotope. This was to be a naval weapon: the ship had a nuclear facility for continuously generating and purifying the isotope, as the warheads would decay significantly in a week. It never got off the drawing board, but a description (with the wrong Californium isotope, and gunslingers with nuclear chells) caught the public imagination.

@JohnDallman Yes, the original experiment could not be reproduced, but the biggest issue is actually sample purity.  Since we cannot yet refine hafnium to more than trace concentrations of less than 1%, we can not yet experiment on purified or controllably alloyed samples.  If the first experiment was done on a sample that naturally had an improbably high concentration or a secondary element that aided the reaction, then the technology may still be viable even if it's not yet reproducible.  So, it is still considered a possible viable future tech.

@Nosajimiki: I remain very sceptical.

@JohnDallman Skeptical is fine.  A lot of people are skeptical of FTL travel, but if you're already willing to make the giant leap of faith to allow for FTL, Hafnium bombs are just a tiny step in comparison.
